# React Native/MongoDB: New data is only accessable after reloading application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, react-native

In my react native application a search scene is set as the first element.
If it gets loaded, the application is synchronizing the data with a RESTful API call.

With that, all data gets inserted into the `articles` model. And the data is usable in my search scene without any problem - as expected.

But in my `ArticleContainer` scene (which is used for selecting a search result) the data is not accessible. I have to reload the application. After that the data is accessible.

**SearchContainer.js (Entrypoint)**

```
import Datastore from 'react-native-local-mongodb'
import synchronize from '../../lib/sync'

const Articles = new Datastore({ filename: 'articles' })

export default class SearchContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    synchronize(this.props.navigator)
  }
}
```

**synchronize**

```
export default async function synchronize (navigator) {
  // ...
  collection.insert(data.MainDocs, (err, newDocs) => {
    if (err) console.warn(err)
    else {
      console.log(`inserted ${newDocs.length}`) // Is 200
    }
  })
```

As a result, I get the log message, which many documents have been added (in my case 200).

If I search, all elements are existing, as they can be selectable by the search. Clicking on a result should call the `ArticleContainer`:
But here I can't find any documents at all. The count result is 0.

I have to reload the app. After reloading all data is existing as expected. But of course, I don't want to do a reload.
What is missing here?

**ArticleContainer.js**

```
import Datastore from 'react-native-local-mongodb'
const Articles = new Datastore({ filename: 'articles', autoload: true })

export default class ArticleContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    Articles.count({}, (err, count) => {
      if (err) console.warn(err);
      console.log('Articles', count); // <- Result is 0; expected: 200
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't actualy know how react-native-local-mongodb works but if its saving data to a file loading the same file second time might be the problem. You can try to create the Articles object and pass it to screens through the navigation. This way it can be loaded only one time and can be the same in all screens.

Comment: Are you sure your method updated the store, which will be props passing to your SearchContainer?

Comment: I think so, because after a reload the data is accessable. And for the search the data is also existing immediately. Also I've used a callback for insert, so it should really be inserted to the db.

Answer (score 0):

I "work around" this problem with this:

In my views that need load after same service update/insert new data I remove this:

```
const User = new Datastore({ filename: 'users', autoload: true })
```

And after a small delay:

```
setTimeout(() => { this._getCurretUser(); },1000);
```

I reload the Datastore:

```
var User = new Datastore({ filename: 'users' });
User.loadDatabase( (err) => {
  User.findOne({ isCurrentUser: true }, (err, result) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      this.setState({ currentUser: result });
    }
   });
});
```

I think that the lib must be updated...
I look for some time for how to solve this and after some reading in the lib code this is the way to do it.